# Associate an application pool to site with appcmd

Tags: iis, configuration, iis-7, appcmd

I want create a site by command line using appcmd.

How can I associate a specific application pool to site?

To create a site, I write in this way:

```
appcmd add site /name:"prova" bindings:http://localhost:8080 /physicalPath:c:\sites\prova
```

Comment: Command need one more forward slash before `bindings` like this 
`appcmd add site /name:"prova" /bindings:http://localhost:8080 /physicalPath:c:\sites\prova`

Answer (score 48, accepted):

You can do this:

> `APPCMD.exe set app "prova/" /applicationPool:"YOUR_APP_POOL_NAME_HERE"`

Note the trailing slash appended to `prova`, that's important.

For example if I wish to set the application pool for `prova` to the `DefaultAppPool` I would issue the following command:

> `APPCMD.exe set app "prova/" /applicationPool:"DefaultAppPool"`

Picking up from Chris's comment below, if you have an existing application in your site, say `/mybloggy` and you wish to change application pool it belongs to then you'd issue the following:

> `APPCMD.exe set app "prova/mybloggy" /applicationPool:"DefaultAppPool"`

Comment: I have apps under ***Default Web Site***

Comment: The syntax for the app name is set app "<site name>/<app name>". This answer threw me off when I was trying to set the app pool for an application in my site.

Comment: @Chris - yes that would be the case where you already have an application under the site root, say `/mybloggy`. The example given sets the site root (`/`) application's app pool. I've updated my answer to make this clearer.

Comment: Can you help to understand How to start the apps under default web site ?? I am able to start the default website in some cases I need to start the web application under the site manually so need to automate that using appcmd.exeto start the same.

Comment: Good job done by @Kev!

Answer (score 5):

Alternative syntax:

> `APPCMD.exe set site /site.name:"Site name" /[path='/'].applicationPool:"App Pool Name"`

Found in Windows Server docs:
https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc732992(v=ws.10).aspx

Answer (score 0):

Although the OP was looking to assign the app pool within the "add site" command, I couldn't find a way to include it with the original "add site" command. I got it working using "add site" followed by "set site" using syntax by **Kev** above.

On the other hand, if you ever need to add an "**application**" under that "**site**", you **can** specify the app pool when you use the "add app" command with the `applicationPool` argument as here:

```
APPCMD add app /site.name:"prova" /path:/App1 /physicalPath:c:\sites\prova\App1 /applicationPool:"provaAppPool"
```

p.s. You may need to prefix APPCMD with `%systemroot%\system32\inetsrv\` and call

```
%systemroot%\system32\inetsrv\APPCMD /site.name:"prova"...
```